# composer doesn't use imported variable

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I import a json file that define variables to be used by composer. 
I used the [gcloud beta composer environments storage data import](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/composer/environments/storage/data/import) command, I can see that the file is imported correctly to the <composer_bkt>/data/variables, however, when I accessed to airflow webUI, I find that there is no variable declared !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the file to to `<COMPOSER_BCKT>/data/variables` is not enough by itself to import the variables to Airflow. Apart from that you need to run the Airflow CLI [command](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.2/cli.html#variables):

```
airflow variables --i <JSON_FILE>
```

To do that in Composer you have to run the following command as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-cli#running-commands):

```
gcloud composer environments run <ENVIRONMENT_NAME> --location=<LOCATION> variables -- --i /home/airflow/gcs/data/variables/variables.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer @itroulli. It appears that my composer version (v2.2.5) failed on that command, but instead a command of this form worked:

```
gcloud composer environments run <ENVIRONMENT_NAME> --location=<LOCATION> variables -- import /home/airflow/gcs/data/variables/variables.json
```

I'll leave this for anyone else that comes across this problem